# What does the color of the "next turn" button mean?

Tags: master-of-orion-2016

Sometimes the "next turn" button is colored blue, sometimes yellow and sometimes orange/red. What does it signify?

Comment: Is this question still relevant with the new early release updates? The Next Turn button is different colors (and text) depending on actions the game wants you to perform. Blue = Assign Research, Orange = Assign Production, Red = Order Fleet, Green = Next Turn.

Comment: @JackBNimble oh cool, can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Next Turn button is different colors (and text) depending on actions the game wants you to perform.

- Blue = Choose Research
- Orange = Assign Production
- Red = A Fleet Needs Orders
- Purple = Spy Waiting for Orders
- Green = Next Turn.

Clicking on any of those except Next Turn will take you either to the Research Screen, the Planet which needs  production, the fleet which needs orders, etc.